# how to add a dot at any position in a string in R using gsub and regex

Tags: r, regex, string, gsub

I use the following code to add a dot after the third position in my string

```
x = "X012345"
y = gsub('^(.{3})(.*)$', '\\1.\\2', x)
print(y)
[1] "X01.2345"
```

I need this to become more general. I want to be able to put my dot after any character of my choice. So the '3' in the gsub command should become a variable.

I've tested this

```
i = 3
y = gsub('^(.{i})(.*)$', '\\1.\\2', x)
```

but I then get an error:

```
Error in gsub("^(.{i})(.*)$", "\\1.\\2", x) : 
  invalid regular expression '^(.{i})(.*)$', reason 'Invalid contents of {}'
```

Can I achieve what I want to do using gsub & regex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1) sub** Use `sprintf` to insert the number.  Also use `sub` instead of `gsub` and simplify the regular expression slighlty:

```
x <- "X012345"
n <- 3
sub(sprintf('(.{%d})', n), '\\1.', x)
## [1] "X01.2345"
```

**2) stri_sub** If you don't mind using a package then with stringi this works:

```
library(stringi)
`stri_sub<-`(x, n+1, n, value = ".")
## [1] "X01.2345"
```

**3) zero-width regex** This has a simpler second argument to `sub` but the first argument is more complex.  It uses a zero width expression -- see `?regex` for more info.

```
sub(sprintf("(?<=.{%d})", n), ".", x, perl = TRUE)
## [1] "X01.2345"
```

**4) fn$**  Another approach if a package is ok is to use `fn$` from gsubfn to insert `n`.  This is close to one of the attempts in the question.

```
library(gsubfn)
fn$sub('(.{$n})', '\\1.', x)
## [1] "X01.2345"
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you want to put it into a function.

```
gsub_dot <- function(x, i) gsub(paste0('^(.{', i, '})(.*)$'), '\\1.\\2', x)

gsub_dot(x = "X012345", 1)

[1] "X.012345"
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `substring` and `paste0`:

```r
sub_dot <- function(x, i) paste0(substring(x, 1, i), ".", substring(x, i + 1))
sub_dot(x, 3)
#[1] "X01.2345"
```

Or, in one call:

```r
sub_dot <- function(x, i) paste(substring(x, c(1, i+1), c(i, 10000)), collapse = ".")
```

Comment: This over-writes the 4th character rather than inserting a period before it.

Comment: Oh, true! Did not notice